# Php foreach loop without to override variables

Tags: php, foreach

I have difficult times to figure out how to manage my loop to not override variables during the process, my example script looks as it follows

```
$targets = array(
    array(
        'site_id' => 1,
        'url' => array('http://example.com','http://test.com'),
        'title' => "Title_1",
        'int_link' => "/internal_link/",
        'icon' => '/icon_2.gif',
        'teaser_index' => 5),
  array(
        'site_id' => 2,
        'url' => array('http://example2.com','http://test2.com'),
        'title' => "Title_2",
        'int_link' => "/internal_link/",
        'icon' => '/icon_2.gif',
        'teaser_index' => 5)
)

foreach($targets as $target){
        $images = array();
    $links  = array();
    $name = array();
        $loop=-1; 
        foreach($target['url'] as $url){
           $loop++;
           //parsing $url;
           //the insider loop has 2 iterations
             if ($loop=1){

                 $content .="<div>".$target['title'].$url"</div>";

            } 
             else{
                 $content .="<div>".$target['title'].$url"</div>";
            }

}
//write $content html to database, without to override the first $content 
}
```

Comment: And which variables are "overridden" specifically? What's with $links and $name; you're ot using them, right?

Comment: the $content is the variable what is overwritten Inside of my loops when I'm creating the html those variable having there roles.

Comment: Why don't you just give the `$content` variable another name that isn't used already?

Comment: I have been trying that to put all the content in an array and implode when it's written to database , but my if condition because of unknown reasons doesn't seems to work

Comment: The question isn't clear, please add more context and/or explain what you intend your code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but i think i understand what the likely problem might be

There are so many errors in the script which you need to fix maybe your script would run the way you want it to be .

A. `$content` was not define .. you need to define it

B. `if ($loop=1){` should be `if ($loop == 1){`

C. `$content .="<div>".$target['title'].$url"</div>";` is missing `.` and it should be something like this `$content .= "<div>" . $target['title'] . $url . "</div>";`

D.  You if condition does not make sense since you are outputting the same information

Form what i can see you want to output Title & URL you can as well just use this simple script  (Just Guessing)

```
$targets = array(
    array(
        'site_id' => 1,
        'url' => array('http://example.com','http://test.com'),
        'title' => "Title_1",
        'int_link' => "/internal_link/",
        'icon' => '/icon_2.gif',
        'teaser_index' => 5),
  array(
        'site_id' => 2,
        'url' => array('http://example2.com','http://test2.com'),
        'title' => "Title_2",
        'int_link' => "/internal_link/",
        'icon' => '/icon_2.gif',
        'teaser_index' => 5)
);

foreach ( $targets as $target ) {
    $content = "";
    $output = "<div> %s : %s </div>";
    $content .= sprintf($output, $target['title'], implode(" , ",$target['url'])); 
    echo $content;
    // write $content html to database, without to override the first $content
}
```

Output

```
Title_1 : http://example.com , http://test.com
Title_2 : http://example2.com , http://test2.com
```